# PayPal cURL Cert error setting certificate verify location

Tags: php, iis, ssl, curl, paypal

So I've been sitting here for about six hours straight trying to figure out why my PHP sample code isn't working. Everything works up until the point where I have to verify over cURL with PayPal. Below you can see my code and my error. I have been trying various methods about read/write permissions, PHP 5.3.7 or greater, php.ini modifying versus modifying my php script. I am completely out of ideas, any help would be greatly appreciated.

PHP:

```
<?php

// STEP 1: read POST data

// Reading POSTed data directly from $_POST causes serialization issues with array data in the POST.
// Instead, read raw POST data from the input stream. 
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
  $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
  if (count($keyval) == 2)
     $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the IPN message sent from PayPal and prepend 'cmd=_notify-validate'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
   $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
} 
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
   if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
   } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
   }
   $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
$myfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "w");
fwrite($myfile,$req);


// Step 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate

$ch = curl_init('https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// In wamp-like environments that do not come bundled with root authority certificates,
// please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set 
// the directory path of the certificate as shown below:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH,'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ca-bundle.crt');
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    fwrite($myfile, "Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

frwite($myfile,$res);

// inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // The IPN is verified, process it
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
}

// inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // The IPN is verified, process it:
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process the notification

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    fwrite($myfile,"verified");
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    // IPN message values depend upon the type of notification sent.
    // To loop through the &_POST array and print the NV pairs to the screen:
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
      echo $key." = ". $value."<br>";
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
    echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$res ."</b>";
}

?>
```

Error:

```
Got error setting certificate verify location: CAFile:'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ca-bundle.crt' CAPath:none when processing IPN data
```

Comment: Not a php nor wamp person, but that sounds like an issue of your web app not having [permissions/access to stated directory](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/curlphp-2005-11/0038.html)

Comment: Yes I have checked that link before but my permissions are set to full control for Administrator, Administrators, IUSER, IIS_USERS

Comment: See if [sanity check](http://serverfault.com/a/105476) on figuring out the actual user helps (for us ASP.net folk we it's typically the Application Pool User).

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates it is not able to find the ca-bundle.crt file using that path for whatever reason. Have you downloaded ca-bundle.crt from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and is it on the Administrator's desktop?

Try putting ca-bundle.crt in the same folder as ipn.php and using the code they provide to verify that it is a path issue and not something else:

```
$cert = __DIR__ . "./ca-bundle.crt";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
```

Also, Paypal's sandbox is www (for some reason) so you will need to use the following otherwise VERIFYHOST will fail:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
```

You might want to grab the updated code samples Paypal is linking to now at https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples